# How to upload/download file from GCS to/from ftp server with Airflow FTPHook

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am currently trying to use the FTPHook in Airflow in order to upload and download file to/from a remote ftp. But I'm not sure if I can use the gs:// path as part of the source/destination path.
I currently don't want to use local folder within the AF pod since the file size might get big, so I would rather use gcs path directly or gcs file stream.

```
conn = FTPHook(ftp_conn_id='ftp_default')
conn.store_file('in', 'gs://bucket_name/file_name.txt')
```

link to the FTPHook code:
[here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/c37fc0b6ba19e3fe5656ae37cef9b59cef3c29e8/airflow/contrib/hooks/ftp_hook.py#L151)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCS does not implement FTP support, so this won't work.
It looks like FTP hook only knows how to deal with a local file path or buffer, not one of the GCS APIs.

You might be able to find (or write) some code that reads from FTP and writes to GCS.

Comment: Thank you for that Mike. I'll start dig into that.

Comment: btw, can you do that without using temporary memory that will store the file? since my AF is running on docker, I'm not sure how it will handle storing the file locally if the files is too big

Comment: You would have to find/write code that does the transfer chunk-by-chunk, to avoid loading the entire object into memory.

Comment: Thank you so much for That Mike. But I do have one more questions since you're working on GCS. Why in c# the google-cloud-storage library it is super easy to get a stream to gcs file, and the Python library it is not included ? (I'll have to use the boto or to implement something like this: https://dev.to/sethmichaellarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h)

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple streaming solution to upload/download from gcs to ftp server and vice versa using pysftp which I'll like to share with you.
First, I found [this](https://dev.to/sethmichaellarson/python-data-streaming-to-google-cloud-storage-with-resumable-uploads-458h) solution, which was working great, but the only issue with that solution was that it didn't support upload file from gcs to FTP. So I was looking for something else.
So than I was looking into different approach, so I've found this google [document](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html) which basically allow you to stream to/from blob file which was exactly what I was looking for.

```
        params = BaseHook.get_connection(self.ftp_conn_id)
        cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
        cnopts.hostkeys = None
        ftp = pysftp.Connection(host=params.host, username=params.login, password=params.password,
                                 port=params.port,
                                 cnopts=cnopts)

        #This will download file from FTP server to GCS location
        with ftp.open(self.ftp_folder + '/' + file_to_load, 'r+') as remote_file:
            blob = bucket.blob(self.gcs_prefix + file_to_load)
            blob.upload_from_file(remote_file)

        #This will upload file from GCS to FTP server
        with sftp.open(self.ftp_folder + '/' +file_name,'w+') as remote_file:
            blob = bucket.blob(fileObject['name'])
            blob.download_to_file(remote_file)
```